# Formatting raw text gathered from another website using php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to retrieve a table from another website, which is based on several variables passed to it via a form.  I have worked out that the url details after the ? correspond to those variables and have created a form on my page to post those variables and create url, which I have then put into a `file_get_contents` process, whereby I collect the table as data (I have narrowed the `get` to the `div` in which the table is housed).

My problem is that the data is shown as a string of plain text on my page with no formatting (i.e. no columns or rows).

Here is the code to retrieve the data:

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents($stats_url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div) {
    // Loop through the DIVs looking for one withan id of "content"
    // Then echo out its contents (pardon the pun)
    if ($div->getAttribute('id') === 'statstable') {
         echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
?>
```

Here is a sample of the data returned:

> NameGamesInnsNot OutsRunsHigh ScoreAvg50's100'sDucksStrike RateBowled (%)Caught (%)LBW (%)Stumped (%)Run Out (%)Not Out (%)Did Not Bat (%)%Games Won%Games Drawn%Games Lost%Team RunsCatchesStumpingsRun OutsOwais Fareed 1  1  0  72  7272  1  0  0  - 0  1 (100)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  42.6  0  0  0  Atif Ali 2  2  0  28  2814  0  0  1  - 2 (100)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  11.62  0  0  0  Craig Hills 2  2  0  20  1310  0  0  0  - 0  1 (50)   1 (50)   0  0  0  0  0  0  100  8.3  1  0  0  Dale Skeath 2  2  0  16  128  0  0  0  - 1 (50)   1 (50)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  6.64  1  0  0  ash ashim 2  2  1  16  10*16  0  0  0  - 0  1 (50)   0  0  0  1 (50)   0  0  0  100  6.64  0  0  0  Hussain Dalvi 1  1  0  11  1111  0  0  0  - 0  1 (100)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  6.51  0  0  0  Azhar Ali 1  1  0  11  1111  0  0  0  - 0  1 (100)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  6.51  0  0  0  A Hammed 1  1  0  10  1010  0  0  0  - 0  1 (100)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  5.92  0  0  0  M Ali 1  1  0  5  55  0  0  0  - 1 (100)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  2.96  0  0  0  Simon Pleasant 1  1  0  5  55  0  0  0  - 0  1 (100)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  6.94  0  0  0

How can I then take this text and recompile it as a table?

Comment: What does the string look like? How are you getting / parsing the HTML? What does the output look like? We don't have a crystal ball to have any idea what is going on.

Comment: @PeeHaa - you should use a boiling cauldron. Crystal ball is in the process of deprecation. - user: you need to update this question with an example of the actual string you get back. We can tell you how to parse it if possible.

Comment: @KaiQing Damnit. Why did I miss that RFC :(

Comment: Ok, I think that the text format is single space separators...  So is there a script that will convert this to a table?

Comment: Apologies I am a little new to all this.  Here is an example of the string that is returned:

Comment: Please [edit you question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13692586/edit) to add the code and samples you have for us.

Comment: NameGamesInnsNot OutsRunsHigh ScoreAvg50's100'sDucksStrike RateBowled (%)Caught (%)LBW (%)Stumped (%)Run Out (%)Not Out (%)Did Not Bat (%)%Games Won%Games Drawn%Games Lost%Team RunsCatchesStumpingsRun OutsOwais Fareed 1  1  0  72  7272  1  0  0  - 0  1 (100)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  42.6  0  0  0  Atif Ali 2  2  0  28  2814  0  0  1  - 2 (100)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  11.62  0  0  0  Craig Hills 2  2  0  20  1310  0  0  0  - 0  1 (50)   1 (50)   0  0  0  0  0  0  100  8.3  1  0  0  Dale Skeath 2  2  0  16  128  0  0  0  - 1 (50)   1 (50)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  6.64  1  0  0

Comment: WOW! Your only hope here is that it is tab delimited. tabs will come through as an invisible marker \t in files. try explode("\t", $page) and see if it at least splits it into individual lines.

Comment: I dont think that has made any difference.  could you possibly confirm where I need to put the explode command?

Comment: Still need help with this? If so, I will need the exact content of the $page variable or a significant part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

It works brilliantly for this stuff.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The builtin DOM parser he's already using should work just fine. The problem is that the `<div>` he's reading seems to contain assorted plain text.